# My monitor constantly changes from DVI-D to HD15

Tags: dvi

I noticed this lately, and it's becoming more often. Basically, when I start my PC, my monitor, which is connected with a DVI-D cable (I don't know what it's called), screen switches to the HD15, where HD15 isn't connected at all. Like, input is changed from DVI-D to HD15, therefore it just blacks out, and then goes back... it's not constant, but it's in random time intervals... I can't do anything on my computer because of this. I even tried connecting it with both DVI-D cable and HD15 cable to the processor, but it still sucks. Is there any way I could force my monitor to stay at only one input method? I'm on XP SP3, and this monitor is about 10 or less years old, a Sony model.

EDIT: also, I think DVI-D is just damaged, and HD15 isn't because whenever it connects to the DVI-D, it shows (sometimes) - no signal, which is not the case with HD15, because when it connects to it, the image stays.
Yes, I tried to connect my computer with another monitor, and it worked, so the problem is in my monitor.

Comment: You'll need to troubleshoot the hardware -- Try the monitor on another computer, if it still does it, the monitor is pooched.  Try the reverse -- use a known-good monitor on your computer, if it does it as well, then it's something about your computer.

Comment: @techie007 I tried with another monitor and it worked perfectly, so the problem lays in my monitor.

Comment: That's what I figured, classic sign of a dying monitor. The fix? Replace it; the repair cost wouldn't be worth it.

Comment: @techie007 Isn't there a way to force it to only stay at one input method?

Comment: Yeah, repair the dying electronics inside the monitor. :)

Comment: @techie007 While I'm still here, does it actually matter which monitor I will buy, I mean, I need something average, and any label is fine?

Comment: It matters, but too much of that revolves around opinion. Your Sony monitor lasted you 10 years, that's pretty good, so why not, if you can afford it, buy another Sony?  Or an LG, or an HP, or a Samsung, or something by someone you've heard of before.  OR go cheap and buy the cheapest no-name crap LCD you can find -- your choice. :)

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering about it not being able to connect with my computer/ not being compatible. Thank you once again.

Comment: Some monitors have an auto/manual input select option in the menu,  if not your stuck with changing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you've discovered that another monitor works fine, we can pretty safely assume the Sony LCD monitor has developed a fault, as not sticking to a mode is a classic sign of a dying monitor.

The fix?  Replace it; as the repair cost wouldn't be worth it.